# Divide two-dimensional array by 2 using Linq and then print it

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I've got a task:

[+]Create 4x4 array, fill it with random int values, sort every column from min to max, print this array.
[+]Create a method that will have this array as incoming argument and will double every member of it, and will print it.
[-]Create a method that will have this array as incoming argument and will divide it by 2. Make this using linq and then print the result array.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        int n = 4;
        int[][] arr = new int[4][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                arr[i][j] = random.Next(0, 19);

        Console.WriteLine("Generated array: ");

        PrintArr(arr);

        foreach (int[] mas in arr)
            Array.Sort(mas);

        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted array: ");

        PrintArr(arr);

        DoubleIt(arr);

        DivideIt(arr);
    }

    static void PrintArr(int[][] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                Console.Write("{0,4}", array[i][j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void DoubleIt(int[][] incoming_arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nDoubled array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                incoming_arr[i][j] *= 2;
                Console.Write("{0,4}", incoming_arr[i][j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void DivideIt(int[][] incoming_arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHere will be division by 2.");
        var DividingArr = from arr in incoming_arr
                         select arr;
    }
}
```

I have troubles using linq with two-dimensional array. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of arrays: multidimensional arrays (where a single array can have multiple dimensions) and single-dimensional arrays (where an array has a single dimension).

Since LINQ only works on single-dimensional arrays, you have to model your 2D array as a 1D array whose elements are 1D arrays. So instead of `int[4,4]` you need `int[4][4]`.

I recommend you make an array of 4 columns, where each column is an array of 4 rows. That will make it easier to sort the columns individually.

Here's how you can use LINQ to make your array of arrays:

```
var rand = new Random();
var array = (from col in Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
             select (from row in Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
                     select rand.Next()).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

And here's how you can use LINQ to operate on each element of the array (in this case to divide by 2):

```
var half = (from col in array
            select (from row in col
                    select row / 2).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Note that this creates a *new* array rather than modifying your existing one.

Comment: I've already sorted, using Array.Sort(); but thank you.